# Upgrading a laravel 5.4 project to laravel 7

Tags: laravel

Is it even worth it upgrading a laravel 5.4 project to laravel 7 which includes many packages ?
Do I have to upgrade it manually version after version or is there any tool that might help with the migration ?
Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By upgrading one version at time, it will be easier to fix and change whats needs to be changed. 
Here is how I did:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade

1. Follow the guide
2. Change the code
3. Test your code

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade

1. Follow the guide
2. Change the code
3. Test your code

And so on.
Depends on the size of your project. Go to the github pages of your third party packages to check if they have updated as well. You can always change the package.

It will be a pain in the ass, but it's possible.
(Don't forget the php version.)

Good luck!